# Missing primary key property in Realm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

The error I'm getting says `Missing primary key property 'email'`.  I'm completely new to databases and would like to know what the issue is with my code.

Also, am I writing to the database correctly?  If I were to successfully place items into the database, how would I be then able to view it?

I've looked around SO and Google for this, but can't to find a concrete answer.

[error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSk4W.png)

Here's `.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Third from './Third';

class Second extends Component {
    onButtonPress() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'Third' // .js file name
        });
    }

    render() {
        const Realm = require('realm');

        class Email {}
            Email.schema = {
                name: 'Email',
                primaryKey: 'email',
                properties: {
                    name: 'string',
                },
        };

        const realm = new Realm({schema: [Email]});

// Query
        let email = realm.objects('Email');
        // email.length // => 0

// Write
        realm.write(() => {
            email = realm.create('Email', {
                name: 'something',
            });
        });

        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    placeholder={" email"}
                />

                <TextInput
                    style={styles.userInput}
                    placeholder={" password"}
                    secureTextEntry={true}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} style={styles.buttonText}>Submit</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20 // makes button horizontally longer.
    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        height: 40,
        borderWidth: 4

    },

    userInput: {
        marginBottom: 20,
        backgroundColor: '#9b42f4',
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1
    },

    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#41bbf4',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        marginBottom: 20,
        borderRadius: 10
    },

    buttonText: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#FFFFFF'
    }
});

export default Second;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have `email` as the primary key in your schema, which become a required property when you create an `Email` object. Did you mean to have `name` as the primary key instead of `email`? Or something like an `id` property.

One way to get rid of this error is to replace `email` in your primaryKey setting with `name`.

For viewing you data, you can use https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx, but it is only available on Mac OS right now.

P.S. when you make schema changes, you would want to delete the app and reinstall it. It is fine for now if you are just start developing it. 
Later on, you should increase the schema version instead and write migrations after you have you app in the store. (Maybe even start before that)

Comment: I tried replacing `email` with `name` and it worked fine, no errors thrown first time doing this.  Then,  I ran it again to make sure for certain that it works and now I'm getting an error that says `Attempting to create an object of type Email with an existing primary key value 'not implemented'` upon hitting `Submit`.

Comment: you mean deleting the `node_modules` folder and then running `npm install`?

Comment: I mean deleting the app on your simulator and rebuild with react-native run-ios or android

Comment: Oops, I should read the error better. This is because primary key must be unique. You cannot create two objects of the same primary key.

Comment: Where am I doing that in my code?  I don't see that.

Comment: Data persists in realm. And every time you render you are trying to create a new Email object with the same name.

Comment: You can use update instead of creation to update the object in realm. Essentially that means adding ‘true’ as the third param to the create method. Check https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#updating-objects for detail.